# If I use just the LiDAR scanned surface in my application my augmented object falls down

Tags: arkit, realitykit, lidar

I have an issue that If I use just the LiDAR scanned surface in my application my augmented object falls down.

I would like to implement a sort of safety net which should be a simple plane and should always be aligned to the lowest altitude on the LiDAR scan.

here is my code :

```
 var lowestY: Float = 0.0
    var planeEntity: ModelEntity?
    
    func setupHorizontalPlaneIn(arView: ARView) {
        // Create a plane mesh with a size of 10 meters by 10 meters
        let planeMesh = MeshResource.generatePlane(width: 10.0, depth: 10.0)
        let planeMaterial = SimpleMaterial(color: UIColor.red, isMetallic: false)
        let planeModel = ModelEntity(mesh: planeMesh, materials: [planeMaterial])
        
        // Create an anchor entity to hold the plane model
        let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal)
        anchorEntity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
        
        // Add the plane model to the anchor entity
        anchorEntity.addChild(planeModel)
        
        // Set the plane entity as static and non-physical
        planeModel.physicsBody = nil
        planeModel.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
        
        // Add the anchor entity to the scene
        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
        
        // Store a reference to the plane entity for future updates
        planeEntity = planeModel
    }
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        for anchor in anchors {
            if let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor, planeAnchor.alignment == .horizontal {
                if planeAnchor.transform.columns.3.y < lowestY {
                    lowestY = planeAnchor.transform.columns.3.y
                    if let planeEntity = planeEntity {
                        // Get the parent anchor entity
                        if let anchorEntity = planeEntity.parent as? AnchorEntity {
                            // Move the anchor entity instead of the plane entity
                            var newPosition = anchorEntity.position
                            newPosition.y = lowestY + 1
                            anchorEntity.position = newPosition
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but this is not working 100% my augmented object gets blurry edges, and it is not interacting with it.

the set up of my AR view :

```
    let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportsSceneReconstruction(.mesh) {
            config.sceneReconstruction = .mesh
        }
        
        // Enable horizontal and vertical plane detection
        config.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
        
        // Enable automatic environment texturing
        config.environmentTexturing = .automatic
        
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options = []
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.receivesLighting)
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.occlusion)
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.collision)
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.physics)
        
        arView.renderOptions = [.disableFaceMesh, .disableHDR, .disableMotionBlur, .disableCameraGrain, .disableDepthOfField]
        
        arView.session.delegate = context.coordinator
        // Run the session with the configuration
        arView.session.run(config)
```

set up of my collision and physics body :

```
    let shapes: [ShapeResource] = [deckShape] + wheelShapes + truckShapes
    
    entity.collision = CollisionComponent(shapes: shapes)
    entity.physicsBody = PhysicsBodyComponent(shapes: shapes, mass: deckMass + 4 * wheelMass + 2 * truckMass, material: PhysicsMaterialResource.generate(friction : deckFriction, restitution : deckRestitution))
    entity.physicsBody?.massProperties.centerOfMass.position = [0.00, 0.07, 0.0]
    
    entity.collision?.filter.mask = [.sceneUnderstanding]
```

`config.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]` is working great until I scan something below it, the most ideal solution would be that this plane detection would move to the lowest scanned point on the LiDAR scanned surface.